# change tableheader on button-click

Tags: javascript, html, tableheader

I would like to write a javascript-function which changes the name of a html-th on button-click. My problem is, that I don't know how to get the "text" of the `th`.

```
document.getElementById("id").text
```

and

```
document.getElementById("id").value
```

don't work.

Comment: Try document.getElementById("id").innerHTML

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ptr3Q/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML`

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="headId">Col name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="getHeadName()" />
```

JS:

```
function getHeadName() {
    var headName = document.getElementById("headId").innerHTML
}
```